# nix-env and nix-build not found after installation (debian buster)

Tags: nix

after the installation following the instructions with

```
curl https://nixos.org/nix/install | sh
```

and logout/login, nix-env and nix-build are not found. 
I had the problem with debian stretch and now with buster. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can try after running: /bin/bash --login on ubuntu

Answer (score 9):

The nix [manual](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ch-installing-binary) instructs to execute

```
source ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh
```

but the instructions printed after the execution say to do (I do not remember exactly)

```
./~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh
```

and the same command is inserted into `~/.profile`. The cause of the problem is the difference between `.` and `source` ([see this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)). The script is setting up the $PATH variable in the environment and has the desired effect wtih `source` but no effect with `.` (which operates in its own shell and closes it at the end).

Cure:
change the line in `.profile` (or better move it to `.bashrc`) to

```
if [ -e /home/xxx/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh ]; then source /home/xxx/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh; fi
```

(`xxx` is your user name),

Comment: There is no difference between `source` and `.`; they are synonyms for the same command.

Comment: There is, however, a big difference between `./~/...` and `. ~/...`; the former is just a path (likely invalid, as you probably don't have a directory named `~` in the current working directory) starting with the current working directory.

Comment: I assume that my memory was not perfect and i left out the space between `.` and `~`. The discussion I quoted above is clearly stating the subtle difference between `source` and `.` - they synonymous on the same command but have different effects on teh environment. Read the discussion!

Comment: The discussion you quoted talks about the difference between a *path* that starts with `.` (resulting in *executing* the script) versus sourcing it (whether with `.` or `source`).

Answer (score 4):

For me only setting `$PATH` like this worked (in `.profile`)

```
export PATH="$PATH:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [this recommended script](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ch-env-variables).

Comment: This is done automatically (and was done), the issue is the difference between ``` and `source`. The script automatically inserted uses `.`.

Comment: @user you mean between `.` and `source`?